# Log in to my web from a chrome extension

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension

I've got a web where logged in users can fill out a form to send information. I wanted my users to do this from a chrome extension too. I managed to get the form to sen information working but I only want to be logged in users to be able to do that. It's like a twitter or Springpad extension when the user first opens up the extension, it would have to log in or register. I saw the following answer at stack overflow: [Login to website with chrome extension and get data from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354029/login-to-website-with-chrome-extension-and-get-data-from-it/5354526#5354526)

I gave it a try and put this code in background.html:

```
function login() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/login", type: "GET", dataType: "html", success: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/login", type: "POST", data: {
                    "email": "me@alberto-elias.com",
                    "password": "mypassword",
                },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
               //now you can parse your report screen
            }
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

In my popup.html I put the following code:

```
var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pageGaffe').val(bkg.getBgText());  
    bkg.login();        
});
```

And on my server, which is in node.js, I've got a console.log that shows user information when he logs in, so I saw that when I load my extension, it does log in. The problem is how can I get the user to log in by itself, instead of manually putting my details in the code, how to stay logged in in the extension and when submitting the form, sending the user's details to the web.

I hope I've managed to explain myself correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before answering this question I would like to bring to your notice that you can [make cross origin xhr from your content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) as of Chrome 13 if you have declared proper [permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions). Here is the extract from the page

> Version note: As of Chrome 13, content scripts can make cross-origin requests to the same servers as the rest of the extension. Before Chrome 13, a content script couldn't directly make requests; instead, it had to send a message to its parent extension asking the extension to make a cross-origin request.

Coming to the point. You simply have to make an XmlHttpRequest to your domain from your extension (content script or background page) and wait for the response.

#### At Server

Read the request and session cookie. If session is valid send proper response, else send an error code. `401` or anything else.

#### At client

If response is proper display it, else display a login link directing to login page of your website.

#### How it works:

It will work if cookies in user's browser is enabled. Whenever user logs in to your website your server sets a session cookie which resides in user's browser. Now with every request that the browser sends to your domain, this cookie is transmitted. This cookie will be transmitted even if the request is from a Google Chrome Extension.

#### Caveat

Make sure you display proper cues to user indicating that they are logged in to your application. Since your UI will be mostly inside the extension, it is possible that user might not be aware of their valid session with your website and they might leave an active session unattended which might be abused if user is accessing it from a public internet kiosk.

Comment: could you provide some sample code for each of the steps you described. I tried going through your code but found it difficult to understand as a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

So the user logs into your server and you know that. I am a bit confused if you then want the user to be able to browse your website with those credentials or a third party website with those credentials.

If it is your website then you should be able to set a cookie that indicates whether they are logged in. Then detect this server side when they navigate your site.

If it is a third party site then the best you can do is create a content script that either fills out the login form and autosubmits for them or analyze the login post data and send it along yourself, then force a refresh.

Comment: What I want is the user to log in to the extension before being able to use it. It's like when using a twitter extension, you log in and then you use it.

Comment: So when user logs in store a server side key and a local side key in local storage. Then you can long poll to expire their key. Although any sophisticated user will be able to bypass by modifying your plugins source code.

Comment: That sounds quite complex for what I wanted to do :P Isn't there a simpler way to log in users to the extension, make sure the user exists and then use the info of that logged in user? Long polling looks complex for something as silly as this. If there's no other way, I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: Sure, just store whether the user login was successful and then expire them after a set amount of time. Long polling would let you have more control server side, but if you don't care about the granularity then just expire them every 24 hours or something.

Comment: So, the user logs in from a form in the extension. The extension calls the server to see if the user exists, and the server gives back a key.  This key would be saved until the user decides to log out, I think this is better than 24 hours because it would be a mess to have to log in everyday. So, the thing is, how is the key saved?

Comment: Chrome extensions feature local storage. Look it up in there docs. It is only accessible from the background page. Not sure about popup.HTML

Comment: I'll try ti implement this and inform of my results. Thanks for your help up till now.